# How to prioritize your clients in NIO server?

Tags: client-server, nio

I am creating a client server program using NIO selector.

The program is to connect to multiple clients at once to the server which is a calculator, now the update required is to give more priority to premium customers (Which i have given a dummy condition as every client with a port number divisible by 5).

1.Is it possible to consider these as normal threads  and complete their execution immediately (Like `thread.join()`)?

2.Will it help if I change the blocking configuration to true and try further

3.Use a separate selector for these clients and complete their execution first?

If not any of these please help me with the solution.

Comment: #3 is the best approach, and run that selector in a higher-priority thread, or process it before the default selector in a single thread. But this won't really have much effect.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I am trying to implement #3 when my next doubt arises ; Can i synchronize between a pool of a threads and a seperate thread(which comprises of my premium customers) in such a way that either the pool or the thread can run at one point of time. To be more preicse; if the clients are free clients then the pool of threads are running, else if the client is premium, these threads stop and the premium thread comes into action --> finishes the work and waits for the next premium client. What would be an efficient and concise method to implemet this?

Comment: Thread priorities, as I said. But they won't have much effect, and deliberately starving a thread that could be running is oretty poor policy. You'll find that the network largely equalizes things anyway. You need to reconsider your business model.

Comment: Thank you, considering your suggestion i have changed the implementation to  using two threads; one for prime clients and the other for free and providing high priority for prime thread. But the issue is, i am not able to register free clients that come to register on the prime thread onto the corresponding thread ad vice-versa. How can i register a client onto the thread other than the one it is running on?

Comment: You need to `wakeup()` the selector concerned before calling `register()`.

Comment: Thanks alot! That actually did the trick.

Comment: Is it possible to split the premium and free clients to two different executors and use the same selector on them?

Answer (score 0):

The approach i used for this question is:
I created 2 selectors; one for prime and one for the remaining and registered the clients accordingly based on a condition that makes them prime. Only one thread with higher priority can access prime selector and the remaining threads access the other selector.
This approach worked for me, though I am still not sure if this is the best method.